# Hyperlink Input Image

Tags: html, css, image, forms, input

I'm struggling to replicate the login form found at the top of the [PayPal website](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/home).

I have been able to create the username and password fields including the 'blue glow' from searching the web for tutorials; however, I'm unable to find any coding to add the 'clickable' question mark to the field.

I would like to be able to replicate the drop down when the question mark is clicked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I hope I have made it clear.

Comment: you should show what you have/tried

Comment: If you have Chrome have you tried using developer tools? (Right-click on the element and click "Inspect Element.")

Comment: Hi Nathan,I had tried that, but having to soft though all their css and html (which is all honesty is all over the place, I thought I would ask people in the know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is in your form have the question-mark image trigger a java-function... Ex:

```
<img src="my_image.jpg" onClick="myjava_function()">
```

Then in your java function you could have a div containing the drop-down displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
myjava_function(){
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display="block"
}
</script>
```

Then in near the form you could have your div that contains the drop down first being hidden but shown on the click.

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;"><form><select><option value=1>1</option></select></form></div>
```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to do this.

Comment: @user1956132: What part are you running into issues with? When I go to the link you provided I do not see the onClick call added.

Comment: I have created a form, but how do I implement the code that you have wrote into the pre-existing form?

Comment: @user1956132: I know why it doesn't work within the function you have ".style.disply" that should be ".style.display" Sorry I typed too fast and had a typo.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that too! Right so that works, but how do I make the question mark that is inside the input box do that (how do I make it clickable?

Comment: Alright, there are a few methods to do that; I think the easist would be to add css to the image. Add two images above the form and adjust their position with css ex:

<style>
#image_id{position:relative;top:20px;left:300px;}
</style>
Just edit the shift numbers until they are hovering over the input field... another solution is z-index but I am not 100% sure that would work.

Comment: That appears to be working! Thanks.
I have two questions left, if I may?
how does this work with responsive sites?
I'll add this code to the site I'm working on and then upload it for you

Comment: @davedavedave.h: I am not exactly sure what you mean by 'responsive sites'; but this method is pretty standard so it should work on any web-host and in any browser. If you could be more specific by what you mean I would be glad to answer any questions you may have. Anyways I was glad to help and remember to please check off that this was the answer.

Comment: BTW...You are a legend! I have adapted your code to open a new window rather than play around with all the coding for a drop down.

Comment: @davedavedave.h: Thanks, and as I said this is pretty standard procedure; you just need something to call a function and it can execute any possible function as long as it is named properly.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach to getting it done. Firstly, try and get a log that is similar to the question mark, and position it in the div that you would place your  area at. In the CSS for the logo apply float right so that the logo would appear to the right of that div. Then build a whole div that appears when you click the log before hand and give it the CSS display none, hence it would not be shown. Write a javascript function that works with the onclick you apply on the logo that changes the CSS of that div to display block and hence the whole div appears when you click it. The div by itself has a cross mark that could trigger another javascript call to change the CSS to display none. Good luck.